# PHP Echoing out Tags

Tags: php

I am echoing out information that was originally inserted into a MySQL database as:

```
<div><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td><i>sadf</i></td><td>sdf</td></tr><tr><td><font style="font-size: 36px;">sdaf</font></td><td><span style="background-color: yellow;">sadf</span></td></tr></tbody></table>sadfasdf</div><div><br></div>   - John MasCodger
```

I would expect it to echo out with that formatting, however it is literally echoed out with the tags- no format.

Comment: Please send a full code - the code you've sent here doesn't involve PHP at all

Comment: you forgot to include the php code in your post

Comment: Is your MySQL data htmlentitied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
echo html_entity_decode($row["htmlcode"]);
```

Comment: You should explain why you think this solves their problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want HTML tags on your output, you can use [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php).

For example :

```
<?php echo strip_tags($row["html"]); ?>
```